# How do I remove the strip above my menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

[image: .]

Recently a strip has appeared above the menu bar on my mac and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Any ideas? The above photograph of the problem is screen shotted.

Answer (score 8):

That looks the the desktop wallpaper. Try changing wallpaper (or display type; it might be due to the aspect ratio).

Comment: It appears that was the problem, silly me! Thank you so much for your help!